# Empirical Rule. Is it applicable in this case?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

So I ran in this problem: I have to test whether Empirical Rule is applicable. Proportions I got is 73%, 94,7% and 99.1% (within one, two and three standard deviations). I'm worried about 73%. This is quite far away from 68% (that the empirical rule states). I have more than 1500 observations. Can I still state that Empirical Rule works here? What are the acceptable deviations?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have 1500 observations, the central limit theorem should hold. If you're getting that, you've probably miscalculated the mean or standard deviation

Comment: You might also be interested in the SE site for statistics: http://stats.stackexchange.com/ (I'm not saying your question is off-topic here; I just wanted to let you know.)

Comment: Well, I meant I have 1500 random variables, not separate observations. So CLT should not apply here